# Pythonic Swap of 2 lists elements

Tags: python, swap

I found that I have to perform a swap in python and I write something like this:

```
arr[first], arr[second] = arr[second], arr[first]
```

I suppose this is not so pythonic. Does somebody know how to do a swap in python more elegant?

**EDIT:**
I think another example will show my doubts:

```
self.memberlist[someindexA], self.memberlist[someindexB] = self.memberlist[someindexB], self.memberlist[someindexA]
```

is this the only available solution for swap in python?

Comment: What don't you like?  What's wrong with it?  What would you like that could possibly be shorter?  Could you provide pseudo-code for what you think would be better?

Comment: It's a terrible way to write a swap, having to repeat every expression, but it's the best Python can do.  C++'s swap(a, b) is the clean, non-repetitive way of doing swaps, but Python doesn't support that level of indirection, so it can't do that.  Just something to live with; every language has its limitations, and this is a minor one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The one thing I might change in your example code: if you're going to use some long name such as `self.memberlist` over an over again, it's often more readable to alias ("assign") it to a shorter name first.  So for example instead of the long, hard-to-read:

```
self.memberlist[someindexA], self.memberlist[someindexB] = self.memberlist[someindexB], self.memberlist[someindexA]
```

you could code:

```
L = self.memberlist
L[someindexA], L[someindexB] = L[someindexB], L[someindexA]
```

Remember that Python works by-reference so L refers to exactly the same object as `self.memberlist`, NOT a copy (by the same token, the assignment is extremely fast no matter how long the list may be, because it's not copied anyway -- it's just one more reference).

I don't think any further complication is warranted, though of course some fancy ones might easily be conceived, such as (for a, b "normal" indices `>=0`):

```
def slicer(a, b):
  return slice(a, b+cmp(b,a), b-a), slice(b, a+cmp(a,b), a-b)

back, forth = slicer(someindexA, someindexB)
self.memberlist[back] = self.memberlist[forth]
```

I think figuring out these kinds of "advanced" uses is a nice conceit, useful mental exercise, and good fun -- I recommend that interested readers, once the general idea is clear, focus on the role of those `+cmp` and how they make things work for the three possibilities (a>b, a<b, a==b) [[not for negative indices, though -- why not, and how would slicer need to change to fix this?]]. But using such a fancy approach in production code would generally be overkill and quite unwarranted, making things murkier and harder to maintain than the simple and straightforward approach.

Remember, [simple is better than complex](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)!

Answer (score 16):

```
a, b = b, a
```

[Is a perfectly Pythonic idiom.](http://love-python.blogspot.com/2008/02/swap-values-python-way.html) It is short and readable, as long as your variable names are short enough.

Comment: http://www.google.co.il/search?q=python+swap&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to imagine how it could be made more elegant: using a hypothetical built-in function ... `swap_sequence_elements(arr, first, second)` elegant? maybe, but this is in YAGGI territory -- you aren't going to get it ;-) -- and the function call overhead would/should put you off implementing it yourself.

What you have is much more elegant than the alternative in-line way:

```
temp = arr[first]
arr[first] = arr[second]
arr[second] = temp
```

and (bonus!) is faster too (on the not unreasonable assumption that a bytecode `ROT_TWO` is faster than a `LOAD_FAST` plus a `STORE_FAST`).

Answer (score 1):

`a, b = b, a` is about as short as you'll get, it's only three characters (aside from the variable names).. It's about as Python'y as you'll get

One alternative is the usual use-a-temp-variable:

```
self.memberlist[someindexA], self.memberlist[someindexB] = self.memberlist[someindexB], self.memberlist[someindexA]
```

..becomes..

```
temp = self.memberlist[someindexB]
self.memberlist[someindexB] = self.memberlist[someindexA]
self.memberlist[someindexA] = temp
```

..which I think is messier and less "obvious"

Another way, which is maybe a bit more readable with long variable names:

```
a, b = self.memberlist[someindexA], self.memberlist[someindexB]
self.memberlist[someindexA], self.memberlist[someindexB] = b, a
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you could take advantage of the step argument of slice notation to do something like this:

myarr[:2] = myarr[:2][::-1]

I'm not sure this is clearer or more pythonic though...