# Commas in python?

Tags: python, syntax

I want to understand function from random.py: Why the last line looks so?

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None, int=int):
    randbelow = self._randbelow
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = randbelow(i+1) if random is None else int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Why it's not single:

```
x[j] = x[j]
```

Comment: Sorry it seemed to me as x[j] = x[i], i need some sleep=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a, b = b, a` is idiomatic Python for "swap a and b".

```
x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]  # Swaps x[i] and x[j]
```

#### Related Stack Overflow posts:

- [Pythonic Swap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1149802/78845)
- [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/101268/78845) -- [In-place value swapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/102037/78845)

Answer (score 3):

This line swaps element j and element i of x.

Answer (score 2):

this is shorthand for:

```
x[j]=x[i]
x[i]=x[j]
```

Notice though, if you were to do it in two lines, the value of `x[j]` would be overwritten by the new value of `x[i]`. By doing it in one line the way the authors did, the new value of `x[j]` will be set to the old value of `x[i]` and the new value of `x[i]` will be set to the old value of `x[j]`.