# What does this construct do?

Tags: python, data-structures

Example

```
num = [0,3,5,3,0,0,9,8]
```

Output should be

```
[3,5,3,9,8,0,0,0]
```

The solution to this in Python is

```
def moveZeroes(self, nums):
    zero, cur = -1, 0
    while cur < len(nums):
        if  nums[cur] != 0:
            # update zero index when current is not zero
            zero += 1
            nums[cur], nums[zero] = nums[zero], nums[cur]
        cur += 1
```

My question is I have seen similar statement like this a lot

```
nums[cur], nums[zero] = nums[zero], nums[cur]
```

What is this statement in particular doing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750039/commas-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

The idiom

```
>>> a, b = b, a
```

swaps the values hold in `a` and `b` in one step so that `a` now points to the value that `b` used to point to, et vice versa:

```
>>> a, b = 1, 2
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> a, b = b, a
>>> a
2
>>> b
1
```

Technically, the right-hand side creates a throwaway tuple, and the left-hand side is a tuple-unpacking assignment.

```
nums[cur], nums[zero] = nums[zero], nums[cur]
```

then means "swap the elements at index `zero` and at index `cur`.

Answer (score 0):

This code `nums[cur], nums[zero] = nums[zero], nums[cur]` is *swapping* two values in the `nums` array. It is the same as if you had written:

```
temp = nums[cur]
nums[cur] = nums[zero]
nums[zero] = temp
```

When you use commas on both sides of the `=` assignment operator, Python essentially makes all of the assignments at once, so you don't need a `temp` variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. So is initial value of zero = -1 and cur = 0 in the statement    zero, cur = -1, 0

Comment: Since `zero` and `cur` are array indexes, the swap would fail if either of them had the value `-1`, since that isn't a valid index. But this never happens, because the swap statement in the loop is preceded by `zero += 1`. Also note that the code doesn't swap the *values* of the `zero` and `cur` variables, it swaps the two array elements corresponding to each value. For example if `zero` is `3` and `cur` is `7`, it will swap the fourth and eighth array elements (since arrays indexes start at `0`).

Answer (score 0):

It is swapping the values.

```
a, b = b, a
```

Now `a` has the value of `b`, and `b` has the value of `a`

Answer (score 0):

It's a variable swap, Python-style. It constructs a `tuple` of two values, the values at `zero` and `cur`, then unpacks that `tuple` and assigns the values to the indices at `cur` and `zero`; by reversing the indices assigned to, it swaps the values.

Note that the code could be simplified dramatically (though possibly at the expense of running slightly slower) by repurposing the `key` argument of the `sort` method to let Python do the work at the C layer:

```
def moveZeroes(self, nums):
    nums.sort(key=lambda x: x == 0)
    # Or more efficiently but obscurely:
    # nums.sort(key=(0).__eq__)
    # Or with an operator import to get speed with less obscurity:
    # nums.sort(key=operator.not_)
```

Since Python's TimSort algorithm is stable, this preserves the order for all the non-zero values while moving the zeroes to the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is Python's **tuple packing and unpacking feature**.

It's functionally identical to

```
temp = nums[cur]
nums[cur] = nums[zero]
nums[zero] = temp
```

but more efficient to the computer and more readable to programmers.

Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14836456/5399734

Answer (score 0):

It is first evaluating both of the values on the right, then it is substituting them to the matching slots on the left. So basically:

```
a, b = b, a
```

is like:

```
c = b
d = a
a = c
b = d
```

It is particularly useful to swap values or perform some operations on them without creating additional variables.